# Pass vales from Javascript back to C# function

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using the following snippet in my Javascript -

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function() {
                    hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                        pageOrigin: {
                            x: this.pageX,
                            y: this.pageY
                        },
                        headingText: this.series.name,
                        maincontentText: 
                                'Value1:' + this.x +
                                ' Value2:' + this.y,
                        width: 300
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 1
        }
    }
},
```

This is part of a function that generates a graph and when a user clicks on a point on the graph, the previous code will load up a popup with the values `this.x` and `this.y` as the body text.

However once the point has been clicked, I need to pass `this.x` and `this.y` back to the C# to use in a function.

I tired to makes 2 variables at the top of the function: `var X` and `var Y` and then set them in the function when the point is clicked like -

```
 headingText: this.series.name,
 maincontentText: 
 'Value1:' + this.x +
 ' Value2:' + this.y,
 width: 300
 X = this.x
 Y = this.y
```

However adding that broke the function with the error-

```
Error: 'chart' is undefined
```

Comment: What actually happened?  "broke the function" doesn't explain the issue.  Do you get errors in the console, or was the server-side code called and there was an error there?

Comment: Adding those two lines brings the error - 'the chat is undefined'

Comment: Where is that error though?  Is it in the console of your browser or is it occurring on the server?  Does it tell you what line of code the error is on?  If so, which one?  You need to be more helpful if you want help.  You need to talk to us as if we know nothing about your project, your code and your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are messing variables with options for expander. This is proper code:

```
           click: function() {

                window.X = this.x;
                window.Y = this.y;

                hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                    pageOrigin: {
                        x: this.pageX,
                        y: this.pageY
                    },
                    headingText: this.series.name,
                    maincontentText: 
                            'Value1:' + this.x +
                            ' Value2:' + this.y,
                    width: 300
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution might be as simple as missing comma(s).

```
 headingText: this.series.name,
 maincontentText: 
 'Value1:' + this.x +
 ' Value2:' + this.y,
 width: 300,
 X = this.x,
 Y = this.y
```

Comment: yes that has fixed the chart undefined error, however how can I then pass those values to the c#? I tried adding -  document.getElementById('myDiv').value= X + Y underneath  Y: this.y, however this rought back same error.

Comment: @Ebikeneser Without knowing how the script is setup it is difficult if not impossible to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add two text box and set display:none;

and then set the value of text box from X and Y and Use them from code behind

```
var x  = this.x;
var y  = this.y; 
$('#TextBox1').val($('#TextBox1').val().replace($('#TextBox1').val(), x));
$('#TextBox2').val($('#TextBox2').val().replace($('#TextBox2').val(), y));
```

Comment: Then you could also have a .NET button hidden and after you populate your textboxes just do $("#hiddenButton").click() and do the postBack to the server. May not be the most elegant solution but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Saparate values with comma(,).

```
width: 300,
 X = this.x,
 Y = this.y
```

you have missed the comma thats why its giving error.